# How to change irregular polygon shape image onclick and onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, adobe-illustrator

I need to create a menu designed with an irregular shape in Adobe Illustrator, I've tried this:

```
  <div class="body_container">
            <img src="img/sitio_Web.png" alt="" usemap="#sitio_Web_Map" height="787" border="0" width="1430">
            <map name="sitio_Web_Map">
                <area shape="poly" alt="" coords="377,164, 377,135, 305,135, 244,138, 194,145, 194,175, 247,168, 309,165, 377,164" href="#Quienes_Somos">
            </map> 
        </div>
```

but I don't know how to proceed on making it a menu with effects on mouse over and mouse click

example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYmMl.gif

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add mouseover and click to the individual sections, then you would need to have each section be an area shape in the map.

```
<map name="sitio_Web_Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="/*first coords*/" href="#Quienes_Somos1">
  <area shape="poly" coords="/*second coords*/" href="#Quienes_Somos2">
  <area shape="poly" coords="/*third coords*/" href="#Quienes_Somos3">
</map>
```

And then you could add a class to any of them for things like mouseover and treat them like you would any other HTML element.

Comment: I get that part, I have the coords for all buttons, but I wouldn't know how to make the class change the image for each specific area on mouseover, do you have clues?